# Send multiple request webhooks teams

Tags: json, microsoft-teams

I'm trying to send multiple message card in same time

When I'm doing a request for only one message with postman, it works for example :

```
{
  "@type": "MessageCard",
  "@context": "http://schema.org/extensions",
  "summary": "Summary",
  "title": "Connector Card HTML formatting",
  "sections": [
    {
        "text": "This is some <strong>bold</strong> text"
    },
}
```

Now i'm doing :

```
{
  "@type": "MessageCard",
  "@context": "http://schema.org/extensions",
  "summary": "Summary",
  "title": "Connector Card HTML formatting",
  "sections": [
    {
        "text": "This is some <strong>bold</strong> text"
    },
},
{
  "@type": "MessageCard",
  "@context": "http://schema.org/extensions",
  "summary": "Summary",
  "title": "Connector Card HTML formatting",
  "sections": [
    {
        "text": "This is some <strong>bold</strong> text"
    },
}
```

And now, I've got this error :

```
Bad payload received by generic incoming webhook.
```

Where is my problem ?

Thanks for your help

Answer (score 0):

Currently you cannot send multiple messages in one request. This is by design. Could you please raise a [user voice](https://microsoftteams.uservoice.com/forums/555103-public-preview/category/182881-developer-platform), Also Please check this [docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/microsoftteams/platform/webhooks-and-connectors/how-to/connectors-using) for more info